# NN stock prediction

Tags: neural-network, prediction

I'm working on school project for NN(neural network) stock prediction I have my yahoo price market data and I normalised my data to number between -1 to 1 my inputs are date and close however I'm not sure what my output should be (I don't know enough knowledge about stock and market) I was thinking of having date and open as my inout and close as my output. I'm planning on using MLP for my project , but is there anything else I need to do after normalisation. I'm not expert on NN I'm taking this course to rise my total grade we were given only one week to finish this HW so I'm not sure if I'll be able to learn using new software

- my inputs are date and open after normalisation what should be the next step
- what  neural network development tool do you recommend (for mac and PC)
- can I use excel NeuroXL add on.. does it work on mac

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're glad you're here. Your question is very broad in scope. A proper answer would be prohibitively large. Visit our [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for some advice on what kind of questions are well suited for this site.